# `at`, `in`, or `on`, which one paired "the top right hand corner" is more appropriate?

Tags: meaning

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/q/1488304/1093117) just now.

> Right clicking the 3 vertical dots (Kebab) button at the top right hand corner, would launch this menu ...

I am not quite sure if it is appropriate I used `at` here.

before I post the question, I've googled. and I got this

[image]

I also searched on [dictionary.cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english-chinese-traditional/?q=at%20the%20top%20right%20hand%20corner) and find nothing.

`at`, `in`, or `on`, which one paired "the top right hand corner" is more appropriate?

Comment: fu DL, do a little more research on "in/on/at" in ELL and ELU, and edit your question to include what you find. You will get more answers if your post shows good research effort.

Comment: Native speaker here, with formal study in language/grammar, working in technology,  so I literally write about the corners of screens all the time.  And - I have no idea how to answer this, so, you'll certainly be understood with any of those. =)   They're mostly interchanegable.   What I can say:  'On' colocates with 'screen', 'at' is often used at the start of a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As a native U.S. speaker (also long in technology), I would balk just a little at the "at" there.  I mean, I cannot call it wrong.  But coming from what is common usage to me, I would expect to see "in" there, as a location where the button "resides."

I would expect "at" used in something more like: "Right clicking the 3 vertical dots (Kebab) button **found** at the top right hand corner, would launch this menu ..."  And in that case, I could just as well expect "found in."

Meanwhile, "on" I would never use in this case.  You may click "on" the button, but I would not find the button "on" the top right-hand corner.  I might find a person leaning against a lamppost "on" a corner, because they are literally standing on it, but not on a screen in technology.

But also interesting to me here is that I had never yet heard of that button called a "kebab" before. :) I just call it the 3 dots or 3 vertical dots. When they are/were 3 short lines, I heard some call it a "burger" or a "sandwich," but I have a low tolerance for accepting that and I refuse to use it. :)