# "menu on top" or "menu on/at the top"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is such a sentence grammatical? (Supposing there's a top nav-bar, at the top of the webpage, with a menu displaying "Profile" as an option)

> You can find your friends by clicking on the "Profile" menu on top.

---

Related thread: [`at`, `in`, or `on`, which one paired "the top right hand corner" is more appropriate?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226472/at-in-or-on-which-one-paired-the-top-right-hand-corner-is-more-approp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatical but not idiomatic. As you did yourself, we say *at the top of the page.*

*On top* describes something physically on another object.

> The surrey with the fringe on top.
>
> The cake had a cherry on top.

Comment: Thank you! But would there be a more idiomatic rephrasing using "on" still? Or should I always use "at the top" to refer to the top of the page?

Comment: Although I didn't find it idiomatic, [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+top+of+the+page&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows that _on top of the page_ has shown a dramatic increase in use since 2000 (though in some cases it refers to one image overlapping another on a compouter screen).